# choose element of ndarray for each element in index array

Tags: python, numpy

I am pretty sure this has already been asked and it has to do with numpy.choose, but I cannot figure out how it is accomplished. Consider the following:

```
N_t = 1000
N_d = 10

X = np.random.random([N_d,N_d,N_t])

jumps = np.random.randint(N_d,size = N_t)
jumps[0] = 0

f = [X[jumps[t],jumps[t-1],t] for t in range(1,N_t)]
```

Is there a "numpy"-way of constructing f? (Side remark: *X* is some kind of transition matrix and *jumps* are the indices of some jump-trajectory in a d-dim state space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's called [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing); You do this by constructing indices for each dimension as integer arrays:

```
X[jumps[1:], jumps[:-1], np.arange(1,N_t)]
```

---

```
np.equal(X[jumps[1:],jumps[:-1],np.arange(1,N_t)], f).all()
# True
```